# iOS WebView, fixed image src name, create image (nsdata, nsbundle, nsurl) dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, nsurl

So my basic problem is, I have a webview containing simple code like

```
<img src="fixedname.jpg">
```

Now I need to set the baseurl so the webview can find the image, but my image
is dynamically created, let's assume I have just the byte data in a NSData object,
how can I add a filename to it or create a NSURL which I can provide the webview?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to save image into local file and set the url of file instead of image name in web view.
try the following
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourDynamicImage);

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* file= [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[data writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file] atomically:YES];
NSURL url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];
```

// pass the [url absoluteString] to the web view
this should work

Comment: thx works fine! i was hoping to somehow pipe it and not to copy the file but works great!